# generate a keystore file in CentOS

Tags: bash, java, centos-6

How do I generate a keystore file in CentOS?
I basically used the following command to generate the  keystore and keys:

> keytool -genkey -alias signFiles -keystore name

however I get the following in my terminal :

> bash: keytool: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Java as keytool is a part of Java.

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I have Java installed and am trying to avoid re-installing Java again as I want to keep my JRE version running on my machine. Is there any work around?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need java6? It's outdated quite a bit already and 7 can do just about everything 6 can do. If you can afford it I honestly would update. As for the work around, I don't think there is to be fair, if memory serves me right keytool is JDK.

Comment: I have a few applications that run off that version. Thanks though I will have to upgrade my java and give feedback thereafter. Cheers,

Comment: i followed your advise and am was able to generate one. Thanks